# How to change shadow color of DropShadowExtender in Asp.net AJAX control toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I don't find any property of DropShadowExtender in Asp.net(3.5) AJAX control toolkit to set shadow color. How to change the shadow color.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You musst override CSS rule like this:

```
#ctl00_SampleContent_Panel1_DropShadow div
{
background-color:purple !important;
}
```